# Javascript indexOf() finds the index of one character, but not that of another character, from a string. Why?

Tags: javascript, indexof

I am trying to use the Javascript `indexOf()` function to find the index position of two characters, viz. `[` and `]` in a string. But it shows strange behavior, i.e. It finds the index of opening-bracket `[` but returns empty string as index of `]`.

There is no error in the `Console` tab of Google Chrome Inspector.

So this is the question. Why is this happening and how should I fix this?

```js
var string = 'allPeoplesArray[0][peopleNameInput]';

var indexOfFirstOpeningBracket = string.indexOf('[');
alert('indexOfFirstOpeningBracket: ' + indexOfFirstOpeningBracket);//check

var indexOfFirstClosingBracket = string.indexOf(']');
alert('indexOfFirstClosingBracket') + indexOfFirstClosingBracket;//check
```

Comment: You are alert is wrong. You should put the variable inside log function.

Comment: Typo  `alert('indexOfFirstClosingBracket' + indexOfFirstClosingBracket);//check ` change like this on second alert
`

Comment: The first comment and first answer are both correct. For future debugging, as yourself, what can `indexOf` return? It either returns the index (a number >= 0), or it returns `-1` in case nothing is found. It will however never return something like an empty string. As such, you know the error lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you closed alert parentheses too soon

```js
var string = 'allPeoplesArray[0][peopleNameInput]';

var indexOfFirstOpeningBracket = string.indexOf('[');
alert('indexOfFirstOpeningBracket: ' + indexOfFirstOpeningBracket);//check

var indexOfFirstClosingBracket = string.indexOf(']');
alert('indexOfFirstClosingBracket' + indexOfFirstClosingBracket);//check
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ebrahim Poursadeqi's answer is absolutely correct. I am just explaining a bit.

```
alert('indexOfFirstClosingBracket') + indexOfFirstClosingBracket;
```

There is an mistake in this line. Notice there is a closing bracket after`'indexOfFirstClosingBracket'`. Remove it from there and place it an the end of the statement.

```
alert('indexOfFirstClosingBracket' + indexOfFirstClosingBracket);
```

And the program will work as desired. Hope this works for you.